# XPages FileUpload control multiple files

Tags: xpages, domino-designer-eclipse

In my XPages application I want to upload multiple files. I've added the attribute "multiple" to the control. Now I can select several files, but only the last selected file is saved.

```
<xp:fileUpload id="fileUpload2" value="#{document1.rtWeb}">
    <xp:this.attrs>
        <xp:attr name="multiple" value="true" />
    </xp:this.attrs>
</xp:fileUpload>
```

What am I doing wrong? Is that the correct way or am I missing the point?

Comment: The xp:fileUpload control does not support uploading multiple files at once (unfortunately)

Comment: That's a pitty, but the 12.0.2 fileUpload control should have more possibilities (https://help.hcltechsw.com/dom_designer/12.0.2/xpageuser/wpd_controls_cref_fileupload.html) but there's no description how the new possibilities are supposed to work.

Comment: If you want to upload multiple files then you have to go outside xpages and develop your own using the [fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#uploading_multiple_files) or similar then handle it using an agent (or an xagent) on the back end. It's not straightforward but can be done.